# raster2pgsql error while loading

Tags: raster, postgresql, import, raster2pgsql

I have done that many times and it usually works but I'm facing a problem now that I do not understand. I'm trying to load a raster (.tif) with a EPSG4326 and it is a one band file in my database from the windows command prompt. I use the following function:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M -R climat.tif -F -t 25x25 clim.climat | psql -h localhost -U postgres -d biotic_interactions
```

it seems at first glance that it is working as I get 0 and 1 inserted and that my new table appears in pgAdmin. However, when I open it in QGIS and I confront the table that I just imported to the initial raster I see the value of the pixels are not the same than in the original file. Also, I noticed that while importing the raster, I get a few NOTICE:

> return error message: numeric field overflow
>   unable to add constraint: nodata_values
>   unable to add constraint: enforce_nodata_values_Rast

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: could you add some details about that *.tif*? e.g. data type, range of values and especially the nodata value. the cast to *NUMERIC* type of the nodata values will most likely be the reason - check comments [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118120/numeric-issue-while-loading-floating-point-valued-geotiff-into-postgis) for a quick explanation.

Comment: actually it is a .adf file but I clipped it in .tif (the problem remains in both formats). the data are integer (each pixel value is correspond to a category of climat/environment) ranging from 1 to 125 (integer values). Nodatavalue=255. I've seen the post you suggested but removing -C does not solve my issue. type=byte.